# Is there any way with Java & SQL Server to extract functions and procedures into one script?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, svn

Sometimes I need to debug production issues at my job. We have a replicated database so that we can see production data, but we don't have the ability to exec procedures or functions. Sometimes the things I need to debug involve a long procedure calling other procedures and functions. Normally I have to open up the first proc, look at what other procs it calls, and eventually put everything into one big script so that I can determine exactly where the production failure happened. I'm looking for a way to programmatically put together that composite SQL.

So I've figured out how to fetch SQL from our SVN using SVNKit in Java. I can parse it to remove the create procedure syntax and everything. The last big obstacle is that sometimes functions are called in-line and those functions may be composed of many lines, loops, or other not-one-in-line-statement friendly SQL.

Is there any way to do this? There is no way we'll receive exec permissions on this server.